Storybook. Args not display after page refresh
I have created a story for a component. The component displays the passed props.
The problem is that when installing controls and refreshing the page, the values ​​are not displayed, although the correct values ​​are indicated in the URL.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ytbumi
storybook config main.ts
// .strorybook/main.ts

import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-vite';
    
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-interactions'],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  typescript: {
    reactDocgen: 'react-docgen-typescript',
  },
};

export default config;

storybook config preview.ts
// .storybook/preview.ts
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;

component
//src/Component/Component.tsx
import React from 'react';

export type ComponentProps = {
  /**
   * label for element
   */
  label: React.ReactNode;
  /**
   * description for label position
   */
  labelPosition?: 'before' | 'after';
};

export const Component = React.forwardRef<HTMLUListElement, ComponentProps>(
  ({ label, labelPosition = 'after', ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <ul ref={ref}>
        <li>label: {label}</li>
        <li>labelPosition: {labelPosition}</li>
        {Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) => (
          <li key={key}>
            {key}: {value?.toString()}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
);

component story in mdx format
//src/Component/__stories__/Component.mdx
import { ArgTypes, Meta, Primary } from '@storybook/blocks';

import * as ComponentStories from './Component.stories';

<Meta title="Component" of={ComponentStories} />

## Default

<Primary />

## API

<ArgTypes />

component story in CSF format
//src/Component/__stories__/Component.stories.tsx
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';

import { ComponentProps, Component } from '../Component';

const meta: Meta<ComponentProps> = {
  component: Component,
  title: 'Component',
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
  },
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Component>;

export const Primary: Story = {};


Use the args property of the Story Meta to pass down the props values (docs here)
const meta: Meta<ComponentProps> = {
  component: Component,
  title: 'Component',
  ...
  args: {
    label: 'Label value', 
  },


Thanks, now the properties are displayed on the page and in the table, but if you change them and refresh the page, they do not change
